# Java диапазон [a:b]

Tags: java, массивы

можете сказать если в например в массиве или в каком то другом упражнение говорит выводить те элементы массива, которые принадлежат диапазону [a:b]
я вот не понимаю,  нужно дать значение a и b, или что-то другое
если не сложно можете написать код

Comment: перебираете элементы из массива, if'ом проверяете удовлетворяет ли значение данному условию, если да, то выводите его на экран.

Comment: Ответы предназначены только для ответов. Раз уж вы уже начали что-то обсуждать с @ТатьянаМотря, можете продолжить [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101528/discussion-on-answer-by---java--ab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int a=0;
    int b=4;
    int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for(int element : array)
        if (a < element & element < b) System.out.println(element);
```

Comment: спс брат, а если я использую двухмерные массивы то тогда это будет работать?  Просто я написал иначе, смотри так будет ли правильно?             double x=2.4;
    double b=15.3;
        int a[][]={{1,1,-7,7},
                  {1,-7,7,7},
                  {-7,7,2,7},
                  {7,7,7,7}};
 for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
         if(i+j>a.length-1 && Math.abs(a[i][j])>x && Math.abs(a[i][j])<b){
                sum=sum+a[i][j];
            }}}
            System.out.println(sum);

Comment: двухмерный массив, это массив в массиве, соответственно там вглубь нужно немного поработать

Comment: int[] a1= {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] a2= {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] a3= {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[][] array2 = {a1, a2, a3};
        for(int[] element2 : array2)
            for(int elementIn : element2) {
                if (a < elementIn & elementIn < b) System.out.println(elementIn);
            }